# List sorting alphabetically

Tags: java

Everything is fine but I want locationName in sorting order,locationMasterList has Integer, String and Double Objects..
Below is my code...

```
List<LocationMaster> locationMasterList = locationMasterService.findByProperty("locationId", locationId);


for (int n = 0; n < locationMasterList.size(); n++) {
    YearwiseBudget yearwiseBudget1 = new YearwiseBudget();
    String locationName = locationMasterList.get(n).getLocationNameE();
    Integer distId = locationMasterList.get(n).getLocationId();
    yearwiseBudget1.setRecordId(recordId.longValue());
    yearwiseBudget1.setAllocation(allocation);
    yearwiseBudget1.setExpenditure(expenditure);
    yearwiseBudget1.setLocationName(locationName);
    yearwiseBudget1.setAllocGen(allocGen);
    yearwiseBudget1.setAllocSC(allocSC);
    yearwiseBudget1.setAllocST(allocST);
    yearwiseBudget1.setExpGen(expGen);
    yearwiseBudget1.setExpSC(expSC);
    yearwiseBudget1.setExpST(expST);
    yearwiseBudget1.setDistrictId(distId);
    YearwiseBudgetList2.add(yearwiseBudget1);
}
```

Comment: You can implement 'Comparable' interface for your 'POJO'.After that you can use 'Collections.sort(YourPojo)'.

Answer (score 0):

Make `YearlyBudget` implement `Comparable` and compare on the `locationName` member.

```
public class YearwiseBudget implements Comparable<YearwiseBudget> {
    private String locationName;
    .
    .
    .

    @Override
    public int compareTo(YearwiseBudget other) {
        return other.locationName.compareTo(locationName);
    }

}
```

Then just use `Collections.sort(List<T> list)` on your list.